# Inheritance Issues

Tags: java, inheritance

I implemented the Following:

```
public class MultiMapClass<K,V> implements MultiMap<K,V> {

    private Map<K, TreeSet<V>> multiMap= new HashMap<K,TreeSet<V>>();


    public MultiMapClass(){

}

public void put(K key, V value){
    multiMap.get(key).add(value);
}

public Set<V> get(K key){
    return multiMap.get(key);
}
}


public class TaggedMultiMapClass<K,T,V>  extends MultiMapClass<K,V> implements TaggedMultiMap<K, V, T> {

private Map<K,HashMap<V,T>> tags = new HashMap<K,HashMap<V,T>>();

public TaggedMultiMapClass(){


}

@Override
public void put(K key, V value, T tag) {
    tags.get(key).put(value,tag);



}

@Override
public T getTag(K key, V val) {
 return tags.get(key).get(val);
}

@Override
public T getTag(TaggedMultiMap.Entry<K, V> entry) {
    return tags.get(entry.getKey()).get(entry.getValue());
}

@Override
public Set<T> getTags(K key) {
    return (Set<T>) tags.get(key).values(); }
```

}

Taggedmultimap suppose be **a multimap**, but I just don't feel right about what I did.
It looks like I just have two different classes with two different representations and no connection at all. If I decide that one object extends from other, does the other have to use some methods of the first? I can't execute the tags thing( each value of the value set has to have a tag of itself) with using  `Map<K, TreeSet<V>> multiMap= new HashMap<K,TreeSet<V>>()` and I don't need `Map<K,HashMap<V,T>> tags = new HashMap<K,HashMap<V,T>>();` in order to use multimap. What should I do?

Comment: Just FYI, your implementation is very prone to NullPointerExceptions. You are calling methods on the return value of Map.get() without any checks and the get() method can return null.

Comment: Could you explain a bit better what are you trying to achieve? I don't understand the TreeSet vs HashMap thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just don't feel right about what I did

You are right about not feeling OK, this is not good. Imgaine, what happens when you do

```
TaggedMultiMap<K, V, T> tmm;
((MultiMap<K,V>)tmm).get(someK); // note you don't override get in TMM
                                 // also note the two get methods of MMC and TMM inspect different maps

((MultiMap<K,V>)tmm).set(someK, someV); // what would the tag be?
```

etc.

> If I decide that one object extends from other, does the other have to use some methods of the first?

Ideally, it should use ALL of it.

The canonical way to use inheritance correctly is to derive from interfaces, which would be `MultiMap<K, V>` (as opposed to `MultiMapClass<K, V>`). Then you have to implement it, which is left as an excercise for the reader... (might not be implementable if you want the user to provide tags for every value)

Comment: I'm looking for a data structure that I can use in the father-class and can be used as well in the other one. Can I define a data structure in the main class that won't use all it's ability, just so I won't need to define another one for the inheritor class?

Answer (score 0):

Is the TaggedMultiMap supposed to have a tag for every of its entries? If yes, then this precondition can be easily violated - you can use the MultiMap interface to insert an entry without a tag in the TaggedMultiMap.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to go with this kind of class hierarchy, then you should override put method in TaggedMultiMapClass like this:

```
@Override
public void put(K key, V value) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

In this way you prevent the addition of untagged values to the map.